# Where is the Spring DM extender for spring 4.1.6?

Tags: java, spring, osgi-bundle

I was able to locate spring bundles for 4.1.6 in the servicemix project but I don't see a spring osgi extender. The extender I was able to locate is only version 1.2.1 and it is giving the following error.

```
2015-06-08 23:33:33 FATAL Launcher:383 - Could not create framework: org.osgi.fr
amework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle 5: package; (&(package=
org.springframework.beans)(version>=2.5.6)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle 5: package;
(&(package=org.springframework.beans)(version>=2.5.6)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
```

I see that 1.2.1 is excluding spring version 4.0+ so what bundle is supposed to be using for Spring 4.1.6 to get it to automatically create contexts for spring OSGI bundles?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible-to build the extender from the source code.

```
git clone https://github.com/eclipse/gemini.blueprint.git
git checkout ac963cca7caa31d4ee43a567a427763cccadc1b0
mvn compile
mvn package
```

This generates 3 bundles which can be found in io/target, core/target, and extender/target, each of which seem to be needed.

In my test host application I needed to export org.apache.commons.logging and org.xml.sax to get it to load.

This isn't an IDEAL solution, but works.